# Angularjs object from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Here my Angularjs application with coffeescript:

```
app.factory "User", ["$http", ($http ) ->
    current: ->
        $http.get("api/users").then (data) ->
            console.log(data.data)
    ]

app.controller "MainCtrl", MainCtrl = ["$scope", "User", ($scope, User) ->
    $scope.user = User.current()
    console.log($scope.user)
]
```

Factory return Promise

Promise {$$state: Object, then: function, catch: function, finally: function}

I need to return an object from the factory:

Object {id: 1, email: "example@example.com", created_at: "2014-05-27T08:21:02.322+10:00", updated_at: "2014-11-17T10:11:31.551+10:00", inn: "25"…}

I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using class methods in your service which is more readable :)

```
app.factory "User", ["$http", ($http ) -> 
    new class User
        constructor: ->
            @current()

        current: ->
            request = $http.get '/api/users'
            request.then (result) =>
                @user = result.data

]
```

Now this is how you are going to get data in your controller

```
User.current().then (user) ->
    $scope.user = user
```